# How to change color of div after first transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is my Code. Initially Div color is black I want it to be changed after div totally has been slided towards right but it changes instantly when i click go button. Solution please ...

```
 $("#go").click(function () {
    $("#subdiv").animate({ "left": "+=75%" }, 1500);
    $('#subdiv').css("background-color", "#293955");
    $("#subdiv").animate({ "left": "-=75%" }, 1500);

}
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a callback for the animation that manipulates the element only after the animation has finished :

```
$("#go").click(function () {
    $("#subdiv").animate({ "left": "+=75%" }, 1500,function(){
        $('#subdiv')
            .css("background-color", "#293955")
            .animate({ "left": "-=75%" }, 1500);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks....I was looking for this solution.... Another thing when it animates to right side horizontal scroll bar also increased as well is there any way so that scroll bar does not get affected through this animate function?

Comment: when you animate the element, you increase it's `left` indentation with 75%. If it exceeds its container's boundaries, the container will add a scrollbar. You can overwrite this default behaviour by putting this css declaration on the container : `overflow : hidden`.